# How to identify UPPER case strings and move place

Tags: pandas, dataframe, move, uppercase

I have created this pandas dataframe:

```
ds = {"col1":["ROSSI Mauro", "Luca Giacomini", "Sonny Crockett"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=ds)
```

Which looks like this:

```
print(df)
             col1
0     ROSSI Mauro
1  Luca Giacomini
2  Sonny Crockett
```

Let's take a look at the column `col1`, which contains some names and last names (in different order).
If a string is in all UPPER case (for example, like `ROSSI` in record 0), then it is a last name and I need to move it after the non all-upper case string.

So, the resulting dataframe would look like this:

```
             col1
0     Mauro ROSSI
1  Luca Giacomini
2  Sonny Crockett
```

Does anyone know how to identify the all-upper case string in col1 and move it after the non all-upper case string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can also use captured groups with regex in `str.replace`:

```
df['col1 new'] = df['col1'].str.replace('([A-Z]+)\\b(.*)', '\\2 \\1')
```

Output:

```
             col1        col1 new
0     ROSSI Mauro     Mauro ROSSI
1  Luca Giacomini  Luca Giacomini
2  Sonny Crockett  Sonny Crockett
```

Using the () to make a captured group, with \b as a word boundary, we can use \2 and \1 to reorder the groups.  With more complex data, you'll probably have to adjust your regex.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a custom function:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace(r'(\S+)\s*(\S+)',
                                    lambda m: f'{m.group(2)} {m.group(1)}'
                                    if m.group(1).isupper() else m.group(0))
```

Or temporary Series and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`str.upper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.upper.html):

```
tmp = df['col1'].str.extract(r'(\S+)\s*(\S+)')

df.loc[tmp[0].str.isupper(), 'col1'] = tmp[1] + ' ' + tmp[0]
```

*NB. this assumes that names are only 2 distinct words, if not you need to adapt the regex accordingly ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CbZGiI/1)).*

Output:

```
             col1
0     Mauro ROSSI
1  Luca Giacomini
2  Sonny Crockett
```